# How does RingCentral localization L10N support work?

Tags: localization, ringcentral, settings

In the RingCentral user extension info API, there is a `regionalSettings` component with three different properties for locale: `language`, `greetingLanguage` and `formattingLocale`. What differentiates these 3 properties and how would you use them when localizing an app?

Here is an example response excerpt:

```
"regionalSettings": {
    "timezone": {
        "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/timezone/58",
        "id": "58",
        "name": "US/Pacific",
        "description": "Pacific Time (US & Canada)",
        "bias": "-480"
    },
    "homeCountry": {
        "uri": "https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/dictionary/country/1",
        "id": "1",
        "name": "United States",
        "isoCode": "US",
        "callingCode": "1"
    },
    "language": {
        "id": "1033",
        "name": "English (United States)",
        "localeCode": "en-US"
    },
    "greetingLanguage": {
        "id": "1033",
        "name": "English (United States)",
        "localeCode": "en-US"
    },
    "formattingLocale": {
        "id": "1033",
        "name": "English (United States)",
        "localeCode": "en-US"
    },
    "timeFormat": "12h"
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API Reference describes the following:

> `language`: User interface language data
>
> `greetingLanguage`: Information on language used for telephony greetings
>
> `formattingLocale`: Formatting language preferences for numbers, dates and currencies

Ref: https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RegionalSettings